# Using methods in one class (classsA) in which another class (classB) is loaded using reflection api java

Tags: java, api, class, reflection, dynamic

I have a requirement as follows. I have loaded a set of classes [present in a jar file] using Reflection in java. Now in the loaded class, I want to call certain methods in the loading class.

For example, assume class A and class B are there. Using reflection I am loading class B from class A. Therefore I am able to use the methods in class B from class A. But I want to use some methods in class A from class B.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: If my answer does not suit your needs please give more details.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a faulty design. Try to rethink it. Your current setup may be solved by applying a **singleton** pattern. For example:

```
abstract class SomeSingleton {

    private static SomeSingleton instance;

    public static void setInstance(SomeSingleton instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public static SomeSingleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public abstract void someMethod();
}

class ClassA extends SomeSingleton {

    public ClassA() {
        SomeSingleton.setInstance(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("some methid is called");
    }
}

class ClassB {

    public void aMethod() {
        SomeSingleton.getInstance().someMethod();
    }
}
```

This way ClassB does not have to know about ClassA. It only knows about a service. ClassA reports to SomeSingleton that it can provide the service. - So everyone is happy.

Answer (score 1):

You could insist that your class B (the loaded class) has a constructor which takes A as a parameter:

```
class B {
    public B(A a) {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

And then in your reflection code, instantiate the class with that constructor.  B can now do whatever it needs with A.  You can create a new instance for a specific constructor like this:

```
Class<B> clazz = B.class;
clazz.getConstructor(new Class[] {A.class}).newInstance(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could let classB implement a method through which you provide an instance of classA and then use this instance from inside classB.

Answer (score 0):

You can ONLY do this by explicitly telling your instance of classB about classA, e.g. by calling

```
b.setA(this)
```

from `a`.